# How to use NTile function within a Partition

Tags: sql, partitioning, rank

I am trying to use an `Ntile` function within a Partition for analysis purposes.
I need the [Lane] column grouped and the [Cost] column in desc order per [Lane].
And the [Quartile] column should be refrencing the [Interest] column

I haven't been able to have the `Ntile` function do its part per lane not entire table.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT LANE, COST, INTEREST
       ,NTILE(3)OVER(ORDER BY COST) AS Q
       ,RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY LANE ORDER BY COST DESC) XX
FROM TABLE
```

I've attached an image of what I would want returned.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
ntile(4) over (partition by lane order by interest)
```